# Nginx Alias for Nagios not working

Tags: linux, debian, nginx, nagios

I am setting up a server as a Nagios monitoring server and I am running into an issue.

If I go to the url nagios.myserver.com/nagios/ (or nagios.myserver.com/nagios/index.php) the server tries to redirect to /opt/nagios/share/s/index.php

The correct folder is: /opt/nagios/share/

I have no idea where that /s/ is coming from.

Error log:

```
2011/11/06 00:16:28 [error] 1818#0: *13 open() "/opt/nagios/share/s/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 75.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, server: nagios.myserver.com, request: "GET /nagios/ HTTP/1.1", host: "nagios.myserver.com"
```

my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nagios.myserver.com.conf file:

```
    server {
        server_name nagios.myserver.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/nagios.myserver.com.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/nagios.myserver.com.error.log;

  auth_basic            "Restricted Nagios Area!";
  auth_basic_user_file  /opt/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users;

        root    /var/www/nagios.myserver.com;
        index   index.php index.html;

   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /opt/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users;
  }

  location /nagios {
    alias /opt/nagios/share/;
  }

  location ~ ^/nagios/(.*\.php)$ {
    alias /opt/nagios/share/$1;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ \.cgi$ {
    root /opt/nagios/sbin/;
    rewrite ^/nagios/cgi-bin/(.*)\.cgi /$1.cgi break;
    fastcgi_param AUTH_USER $remote_user;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

content of fastcgi.conf:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/www/php.sock;
    }
}
```

fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Debug:

```
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 open index "/opt/nagios/share/index.php"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 internal redirect: "/nagios/index.php?"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 generic phase: 1
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 test location: "/"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 test location: "nagios"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/nagios/(.*\.php)$"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 using configuration "\.php$"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 generic phase: 3
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script complex value
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script copy: "/opt/nagios/share/"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script capture: ""
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script copy: "/opt/nagios/share/"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script capture: ""
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script var: "/opt/nagios/share/s/index.php"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script copy: ""
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script file op 00000000 "/opt/nagios/share/s/index.php"
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script file op false
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script if
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 http script if: false
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 access phase: 8
2011/11/06 01:30:29 [debug] 5226#0: *1 access phase: 9
```

I kept some of the debug out as I think this part should help though I still can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

I am pretty new to NginX.

Thanks.

Comment: What about the `fastcgi_params`?

Comment: added it, along with debug.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a rewrite rule somewhere in your config. 
What does `fastcgi.conf` look like?

You can do a quick search with:

```
# grep -lr rewrite /etc/nginx/
# grep -lr include /etc/nginx/
```

Try to change the `location /nagios` to the `location /abc` to see if it redirects to the `/opt/nagios/share/c/index.php`. If it doesn't, I suggest you turning on the debug and take a look the the error log.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will edit my post to includet he fastcgi.conf but it does not seem to have anything that could cause this. When I changed the location /nagios to /abc and typed the url it tried to look for it in /var/www/nagios.myserver.com/abcd

Comment: Post the error log after setting `error_log` to `debug`.

Comment: I just upgraded to Nginx 1.0.9 and now instead of trying for /s/ its changing the url to nagios.myserver.com/nagios/index.php/     Still not working but at least this one should be easier to tackle!